# Is there a way to control tab size in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, tabs, irb

On the console, when I output a string like this:

```
puts "\tFOOBAR"
```

it seems to insert 8 spaces before the `FOOBAR`.

Is there any way to control this tab size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That code is not inserting 8 spaces, it is inserting a single tab literal `\t`.  Whatever you are using to *view* it is interpreting and displaying the tab literal as 8 spaces.

If your terminal, for example, is showing 8 spaces, you may be able to change preferences to reduce the display width, but it is definitely not Ruby's doing.  How to change it will depend on the application or terminal.

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense. Tab size can be changed in the console with: `tabs -2` where `2` is the tab size.